# Migrations From Custom Generator Don't Migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I am creating a gem

I have a generator to create a migration based on a name of your choosing

```
rails g my_generator MODEL
```

I am not using rails'

```
rails g migration XYZ
```

But instead pretty much copying what a schema would look like...example: if a user types the following

```
rails g my_generator Item
```

You get:

```
class CreateItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "items", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "title"
      t.integer  "color_id"
      t.integer  "size_id"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.integer  "base_product_id"
      t.integer  "stock_qty"
    end
  end
end
```

The name of the migration is (my_generator)create_items.rb  I have not inserted the timestamp in the start of the migration. That is really the only difference between a `rails g model Item`'s migration, and the one I get from my generator.

My migration doesn't do anything, but I tested creating a new model, and running `rake db:migrate`, the `rails g model` migrates, mine does not.

Here is my generator:

```
 class Rails::ShiftedCommerceGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
      def create_main_model
        create_file "app/models/shifted_commerce/#{plural_name.singularize}.rb", <<-FILE
          class #{class_name} < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :base_#{plural_name.singularize}
            has_many :line_items
            belongs_to :size
            belongs_to :color
            validates_uniqueness_of :base_#{plural_name.singularize}_id, :scope => [:size_id]

            def is_base_#{plural_name.singularize}?
                return true if self.class.name == "Base#{class_name}"   
            end
            def is_#{plural_name.singularize}?
                return true if self.class.name == "#{class_name}"   
            end
            def in_stock
              self.stock_qty > 0
            end

          end
        FILE
      end
      def create_main_migration
        create_file "db/migrate/shifted_commerce_create_#{plural_name}.rb", <<-FILE
        class Create#{class_name} < ActiveRecord::Migration
            def change
                create_table :#{plural_name}, force: true do |t|
                  t.string   :title
                  t.integer  :color_id
                  t.integer  :size_id
                  t.datetime :created_at
                  t.datetime :updated_at
                  t.integer  :base_product_id
                  t.integer  :stock_qty
                  t.timestamps

                end
            end
        end
        FILE
      end
    end
```

Comment: I'll post my generator...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the timestamp when you are generating your own migrations

(not using rails g migration)

Your generator should include something this:

```
create_file "db/migrate/#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}_create_#{plural_name}.rb", <<-FILE
```

the .strftime method is a way to get the timestamp into your migration file the same way rails has it formatted.